# Pico W MQTT SDK

Tags: raspberry-pi-pico

I've found in the SDK folder `pico_lwip` in that CMakeList.txt at line 245 the added mqtt library.
My internet search did not provide me with the necessary information how to use this implementation.

In my CMakeList.txt I added the `pico_lwip_mqtt` to my target link libraries. If anyone can help me or provide me with an example, it would be very helpful!